# Swarm compose file for Jenkins agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-swarm, jenkins-agent

I am trying to create a compose file for `jenkins/slave` to run in my single node swarm.
The image I've used is [jenkins/slave](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave)

The `docker` `run` command to use with the image is `docker run -i --rm --name agent1 --init -v agent1-workdir:/home/jenkins/agent jenkins/agent java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar -workDir /home/jenkins/agent`
and my compose file looks like below:
('local_registry:5000/jenkins_ansible_slave' is the built image, which I've pushed to my local registry)

```
  slave1:
    image: 'local_registry:5000/jenkins_ansible_slave'
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    init: true
    volumes:
      - "/home/user/agent:/home/jenkins/agent"
    command: "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar -workDir /home/jenkins/agent"
    networks:
      - net
```

`slave1` service is not getting started and I'm getting this error when I checked the service logs

```
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    | INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    | May 03, 2021 3:27:01 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    | INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    | Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:415)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:360)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:762)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.Launcher.runWithStdinStdout(Launcher.java:710)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:396)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    |  at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:296)
DEVOPS-STACK_slave1.1.vcm7tc3i0ral@local_registry    | <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>rO0ABXNyABpodWRzb24ucmVtb3RpbmcuQ2FwYWJpbGl0eQAAAAAAAAABAgABSgAEbWFza3hwAAAAAAAAAf4=
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
stdin_open: true # docker run -i
tty: true        # docker run -t
```

I think this will fix your issue.
You docker-compose config should look like this.

```
  slave1:
    image: 'local_registry:5000/jenkins_ansible_slave'
    ports:
      - "22:22"
    init: true
    volumes:
      - "/home/user/agent:/home/jenkins/agent"
    command: "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar -workDir /home/jenkins/agent"
    networks:
      - net
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
```